# Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068) Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, typescript, cassandra, undefined

I can't understand what is the problem with this code?

```
import cassandra from "cassandra-driver";

class Cass {
static _cass : cassandra.Client;

  this._cass = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['localhost'],
    localDataCenter: 'datacenter1',
    keyspace: 'ks1'
  });
}
```

I get the following error at `this._cass` assignment line:

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
> expected.ts(1068) Object is possibly 'undefined'.

`EDIT` I have a similar class like following that work with no problem, and I am wondering to know why? What is the difference between this class and the previous one?

```
import mysql from "mysql2";
import { Pool } from "mysql2/promise";

class Pools {
  static _pools: Pool;

  static connect(options: mysql.PoolOptions) {
    this._pools = mysql.createPool(options).promise();
    this._pools.execute('SELECT 1 + 1;');
  }

  static close() {
    this._pools.end();
  }

  static execute(sql: string, params?: any[] | undefined) {
    return this._pools.execute(sql, params);
  }
}


export { Pools };
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside class declarations, you cannot use expressions outside of functions or assignements. Also, you have declared `_cass` as static property, so you cannot/should not access it through `this`, as it is a property on the class, not the instance.

It think you want to do something like this:

```js
class Cass {
  static _cass = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['localhost'],
    localDataCenter: 'datacenter1',
    keyspace: 'ks1'
  });
}
```

To be clear, you cannot write statements within class bodies outside functions or for default values in property declarations:

```js
class MyClass{
  console.log('foo') // regular statement, not allowed
  this.toString() // regular statement, not allowed
  myProp = 42 // property declaration with default value, allowed
  this.myProp = 42 // regular statement, not allowed
  static myClassProp = 'bar' // property declaration with default value, allowed
  MyClass.myClassProp = 'bar' // regular statement, not allowed
}
```

Note the difference between a statement like `this.myProp = 42`, which sets an existing property of the instance, and a declaration like `myProp = 42`, which declares the property and sets a default value.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh, thank you, I did not phrase that correctly. Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Please read the edit part I addede to my question.